# get product collection and subcategory id using category id magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to get product collection and subcategory using category id.

I am trying

```
$category =  2;
    $product = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection();
    $product->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $product->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids',$category);
```

But it gives error like this

> Column not found: 1054 Champ 'e.category_ids' inconnu dans where clause,...

And how to get subcategory id from category id?

Answer (score 5):

Please change like this and it will works.

```
$collection = $this->productFactory->create()
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => 2]);
```

Comment: Working fine, resulting as expected

Answer (score 4):

You cannot add a category filter like that because category_id is not an attribute of the product.

The collection object (Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection) though does come with two handy functions to aid in this.

```
addCategoryFilter(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category)
```

and

```
addCategoriesFilter(array $categoriesFilter)
```

In your case the later is probably more suitable so your code may look something like;

```
$collection = $this->productFactory->create()
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => 2]);
```

Comment: The above example with addCategoriesFilter does not work. You need to add an condition type like eq for Equal to, or neq for not equal to.
In above example, change ->addCategoriesFilter([2]); to ->addCategoriesFilter([‘eq’ => 2]); and it should work.