# Add Category filter in best seller product Collection

Tags: magento2, category, best-seller

I get best seller product for all category using below code

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory

) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

 }


public function getBestSellerData()
{
    $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel(
        'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'
    );

    return $collection;
}
```

How can i add category filter for collection. 
in magento 1 we can do like that

```
$catNum = 7; //The number of the category you want to load
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catNum);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addOrderedQty()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->addStoreFilter($storeId)
->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you want to filter the collection in your code based on a category id for instance? Or are you talking about frontend layered navigation filters? Please elaborate.

Comment: i need filter collection based on category id.for ex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971429/magento-store-best-selling-items-by-category

Answer (score 1):

The only product information returned from the reports bestseller collection is as follows:

```
[period] => 2018-01-01
[qty_ordered] => 1.0000
[product_id] => 20
[product_name] => product name
[product_price] => 5.7500
```

hence you will need to do a join and then filter like so

You could also do a join and filter by category

```
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel(
            'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'
        )->join(['secondTable' => 'catalog_category_product'], 'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly.product_id = secondTable.product_id', ['category_id' => 'secondTable.category_id'])
        ->addFieldToFilter('category_id', ['eq' => 43]);
```

Which will give you below:

```
[period] => 2018-01-01
[qty_ordered] => 1.0000
[product_id] => 20
[product_name] => Clipbook Classic Pastels Personal Notebook Orchid
[product_price] => 5.7500
[category_id] => 43
```

So you can `addFieldToFilter()` based on category_id.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the bestseller collection is the same as normal product collection. You can use:

```
addCategoriesFilter(array $categoriesFilter)
```

See also https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100993/5827

Comment: Yes But Question is how can i add addCategoriesFilter in my collection. i share my file pls check https://github.com/pratikmage/best_seller-/blob/master/View.php

Comment: It's as simple as if `$collection->addCategoriesFilter($categoryFilter)`. Here is a tip, if you don't know how to use a method. Just do a search in the Magento 2 repo at github for that method so you could see some actual examples. https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=addCategoriesFilter Like for instance this one: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/d659b4d557ddb016600646127245c59220049530/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php#L616