# Get product collection by category id on phtml file magento2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to get product collection by category id on phtml file. For that I used below code but it's not working.

```
$collection = $this->productFactory->create()
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => 2]);
```

I also tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100976/get-product-collection-and-subcategory-id-using-category-id-magento-2?answertab=active#tab-top) link but when I use **addCategoryFilter(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category)** in my phtml file it shows me error that unexpected **$category** on line no. xx

May I need to add anything to get product collection by category id? I am using **addCategoriesFilter** to get collection by category id. Is it right or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add this in the Block, and call the function  **getProductCollection**() in  phtml,

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;
protected $_categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
) {
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $categoryId = 'yourcategoryid';
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change code in core magento block file so is there any way to get product collection by category id on phtml page directly?

Comment: basically I have change category page. So now category page showing sub-category and I want to show one product for that category on category page. you helped me to get sub-category on category page now I want to showing one product of current category with sub category. How can I get it?

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should not load models or collections in template files. You need to override or change the block. Or create a new one.

Comment: yes you don't need to change core code just create your own block and you can call your phtml file to get collection based on filter.

Comment: @RJ07 can you tell me which block file is responsible for **magento_catalog/templates/category/products.phtml** file so I will override this block and can add **getProductCollection** function.

Comment: Since you have marked this message as the correct one, can you explain what changes you have made?

Comment: @Atr_Max  I have create my custom small module in app/code. In this module I have added block file with above code and one phtml file in this phtml file I call function from block file so I get what I want. And after that I call this phtml file where I want to show product.

Comment: How do i get all categories ? i.e dynamically get category ids in $categoryId = 'yourcategoryid';

Comment: @Rushvi, can we filter collection with only Instock items ?

Answer (score 8):

you can simply call block and get product collection using below code,

Inside BLock file,

```
<?php
namespace Company\Categories\Block;

class Categoryproduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCategoryProduct($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $category;
    }
}
```

call function in your **.phtml** file,

```
$categoryId = 5;
$getProudctcollection = $block->getCategoryProduct($categoryId);

<ul class="category-products">  
                        <?php 
                                foreach ($getProudctcollection as $product) : ?>
                                    <li class="level0-child">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                            <?php echo $product->getName();?>
                                        </a>
                                    </li> 
                        <?php   endforeach;?>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: how to filter collection with Instock items?