# Magento 2: How to get all products using category id

Tags: magento2, product, category-id

I have category id in phtml file. how to display all products under this category using category id and foreach loop.

*I tried this code but it shows invalid variable in foreach*

```
$categoryId = 6; // fetching products in category id 6   
$categoryProducts = $block->getCategoryProducts($categoryId);  
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product){
echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br/>';
}
```

I have a category chooser in block

```
<?php
namespace Product\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Widget;

class Chooser extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template {

protected $_elementFactory;
/**
* @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
* @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
* @param array $data
*/
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory, array 
$data = []
) {
  $this->_elementFactory = $elementFactory;
  parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
* Prepare chooser element HTML
*
* @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element 
Form Element
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
*/
public function 
prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
  $htmlId = $element->getId();
  $data = $element->getData();

  $data['after_element_js'] = $this->_afterElementJs($element);
  $data['after_element_html'] = $this->_afterElementHtml($element);
  $data['readonly'] = 'readonly';
  $htmlItem = $this->_elementFactory->create('text', ['data' => $data]);
  $htmlItem
          ->setId("{$htmlId}")
          ->setForm($element->getForm())
          ->addClass('required-entry')
          ->addClass('entities');
  $return = <<<HTML
           <div id="{$htmlId}-container" class="chooser_container">{$htmlItem->getElementHtml()}</div>
HTML;
   $element->setData('after_element_html', $return);
  return $element;
 }

 protected function _afterElementHtml($element)
  {
      $htmlId = $element->getId();
    $return = <<<HTML
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="MultiCategoryChooser.displayChooser('{$htmlId}-container')" class="widget-option-chooser" title="{__('Open Chooser')}">
          <img src="{$this->getViewFileUrl('images/rule_chooser_trigger.gif')}" alt="{__('Open Chooser')}" />
      </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="MultiCategoryChooser.hideChooser('{$htmlId}-container')" title="{__('Apply')}">
          <img src="{$this->getViewFileUrl('images/rule_component_apply.gif')}" alt="{__('Apply')}">
      </a>
      <div class="chooser"></div>
   HTML;
  return $return;
  }

  protected function _afterElementJs($element)
  {
  $chooserUrl = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/widget_instance/categories', 
  []);
  $htmlId     = $element->getId();
  $return = <<<HTML
      <script>
              require([
              'jquery',
              'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
              "prototype"
          ], function (jQuery, alert) {
              var MultiCategoryChooser = {
                  displayChooser : function(chooser) {
                          chooser  = $(chooser).down('div.chooser');
                          entities = chooser.up('div.chooser_container').down('input[type="text"].entities').value;
                          postParameters = {selected: entities};
                          url = '{$chooserUrl}';

                          if (chooser && url) {
                          if (chooser.innerHTML == '') {
                                  new Ajax.Request(url, {
                                  method  : 'post',
                                  parameters : postParameters,
                                  onSuccess  : function(transport) {
                                          try {
                                          if (transport.responseText) {
                                              Element.insert(chooser, transport.responseText);
                                              chooser.removeClassName('no-display');
                                              chooser.show();
                                          }
                                          } catch (e) {
                                          alert({
                                             content: 'Error occurs during loading chooser.'
                                          });
                                          }
                                  }
                              });
                          } else {
                              chooser.removeClassName('no-display');
                              chooser.show();
                          }
                          }
                 },
                  hideChooser : function(chooser) {
                          chooser = $(chooser).down('div.chooser');
                          if (chooser) {
                          chooser.addClassName('no-display');
                          chooser.hide();
                          }
                  },
                  checkCategory : function(event) {
                          node    = event.memo.node;
                          container = event.target.up('div.chooser_container');
                          value   = container.down('input[type="text"].entities').value.strip();
                          if (node.attributes.checked) {
                          if (value) ids = value.split(',');
                          else ids = [];
                          if (-1 == ids.indexOf(node.id)) {
                              ids.push(node.id);
                              container.down('input[type="text"].entities').value = ids.join(',');
                          }
                          } else {
                          ids = value.split(',');
                          while (-1 != ids.indexOf(node.id)) {
                              ids.splice(ids.indexOf(node.id), 1);
                              container.down('input[type="text"].entities').value = ids.join(',');
                          }
                          }
                  }
                }
              window.MultiCategoryChooser = MultiCategoryChooser;
              jQuery(function() {
                  var container = $('{$htmlId}-container');
                  if (container) {
                      container.up(0).down('.control-value').hide();
                  }

                  Event.observe(document, 'node:changed', function(event){
                      MultiCategoryChooser.checkCategory(event);
                  });
                  Event.observe(document, 'category:beforeLoad', function(event) {
                          container = event.target.up('div.chooser_container');
                          value   = container.down('input[type="text"].entities').value.strip();
                      event.memo.treeLoader.baseParams.selected = value;
                  });
              });
          });
      </script>
 HTML;
     return $return;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Which phtml file is being used? The block refers to the function of the .php file located in the module Block folder of same name. Do you have getCategoryProducts function within that which needs categoryId arguments. If yes better to share .php code as well.

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382355/how-to-get-products-by-category-id-in-magento-2-2-1. Thanks.

Comment: Please check this link too https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125086/get-product-collection-by-category-id-on-phtml-file-magento2

Comment: The answer by Rakesh in the link shared by Ansar seems best to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can get products by category id by below code

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryId = 6;
$category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
$categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categoryProducts as $product)
{
    echo $product->getName();
}
```

**You should not use the ObjectManager directly!**

Comment: Is that need any additional functionalities in php file  that i have written block folder?

Comment: Yes you can also create function in block file and call to phtml

Comment: public function getCategory($categoryId) 
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
        $category->load($categoryId);
        return $category;
    }
    
    public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
    {
        $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $products;
    }

Comment: how to use object manager

Comment: This is not a correct approach. Magento recommend not to use the object manager directly like this. Instead use DI approach. This will lead to other dependency errors if not found. Because you have created object of model directly. Instead of model you should create object of service contract.