# Magento2: How to get product collection by parent-category-id and sub-category-id?

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection, category-products

How to get product by  parent-category-id and  sub-category-id?

Magento 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$categoryFectory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$productCollection = $categoryFectory->load('category_id')->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: I want to product collection sub-category also.

Comment: Now, I have got single category product collection. But i want sub-category product collection also.

Comment: make parent category is_anchor=yes then it will fetch subcategory products also on the same

Comment: can you tell me where add this code? category is_anchor=yes

Comment: no no not in code just do it from admin category section

Comment: please check link https://ibb.co/eKYw9e

Comment: sub-category product collection is not getting.

Comment: are subcategory also is_anchor=yes ?

Comment: Yes, All categories and sub-categories option is_anchor=yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82772/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-ansar-husain).

Answer (score 1):

Please check this following link for get more idea about it.

[Click here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125086/get-product-collection-by-category-id-on-phtml-file-magento2)