# Is any sql query possible to get all products of a category using category id magento 2

Tags: magento2

> Actually i want to know sql query possible to get all products of a
>   category using category id.

Comment: Try this:

SELECT DISTINCT cc.entity_id as id, cc.value as path, cc1.value as name    
FROM 
    catalog_category_entity_varchar cc    
    JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cc.entity_id=cc1.entity_id    
    JOIN catalog_category_entity cce ON cc.entity_id=cce.entity_id
 WHERE 
    cc.attribute_id = '57' AND 
    cc1.attribute_id = '41' ;

Comment: for get prodcut collection by category id try this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/125092/55928

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the products of a category by 2 methods(In my case category id is 3):

**Method 1:**

```
<?php 
    $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
    $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load(3);
    $categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
```

**Method 2:**

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id='3' AND cat_index.is_parent=1
```

If you try to get the sql query of the product collection of a given category id(Method 1) then you just need to try the below code:

```
echo $categoryProducts->getSelect();
```

By above code you will get the sql of that magento 2 product collection of a category.