# rest api to get product information returns null

Tags: magento2

I'm building an api function that returns me products information based on category id. here is the code:

```
public function getAssignedProducts($categoryId)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $products */
    $products = $category->getProductCollection();



    $items =array();
    $i=1;

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
    foreach ($products->getItems() as $product) {
        $items[$i]['sku'] = $product->getSku();
        $myProduct = $this->getProduct($product->getSku());
        $items[$i]['products'] = $myProduct;
        $items[$i]['name'] = $product->getName();
        $items[$i]['description'] = $product->getData('description');
        $items[$i]['price'] = $product->getPrice();
        $items[$i]['quantity'] = $product->getQty();
        $items[$i]['isAvailable'] = $product->isAvailable();
        $items[$i]["mediaURL"] = $this->getMediaUrl();
        $items[$i]["imageTitle"] = $product->getImage();

        $i++;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

but it returns only sku, isAvailable and image and other information are null

I need to know why

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125086/get-product-collection-by-category-id-on-phtml-file-magento2    use this logic might be help you

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I'll try it, but I need to understand why this is the result

Comment: As per my understand the problem with this line $myProduct = $this->getProduct($product->getSku());

Comment: I deleted this line and same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_productloader;  


    public function __construct(

     \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ){

        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */ 

     public function getAssignedProducts($categoryId)
     {          
         $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
         $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
         $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
         $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
         // Add filter based on requirment
         //$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
         //$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
         //return $collection->getData();        
         $items=[];
         $i=1;       
         foreach($collection as $productdata)
         {
             $product=$this->_productloader->create()->load($productdata->getEntityId());
             $stockItem=$product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
             $items[$i]['sku'] = $product->getSku();
             $items[$i]['name'] = $product->getName();
             $items[$i]['description'] = $product->getData('description');
             $items[$i]['price'] = $product->getPrice();
             $items[$i]['quantity'] = $stockItem->getQty();
             $items[$i]['isAvailable'] = $product->isAvailable();
             $items[$i]["mediaURL"] = $product->getMediaUrl();//Instead of this method use your custom method so it will return media url
             $items[$i]["imageTitle"] = $product->getImage();            
             $i++;
         }
         return $items;

     }
```

Comment: Can you explain me why my code is not working?

Comment: @YomnaMansour please try my code once and let me know your comments. thanks

Comment: I works but I need other information than it returns

Comment: @YomnaMansour i have updated my post with latest infomation except media url please try and getback..