# How to get product collection by categoryId?

Tags: magento2, php

I am getting product collection by categoryId follow this guide
[Get product collection by category id on phtml file magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125086/get-product-collection-by-category-id-on-phtml-file-magento2/125092#125092)

I have problem with number of product collection. When I echo the sql query and run the query in database it have 35 rows result. But print the collection in the block template it have only one result.

My block function as below:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getProudctcollection($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

The code in the template as below:

```
/** @var $block \FSO\Categories\Block\Index\Index;*/
$categoryId = 4;
$productCollection =  $block->getPromotionProductCollection($categoryId);
foreach ($productCollection as $product){
    $product->getId();
    $product->getSku();
    echo "<h1>".$product->getName()."</h1>";
}
```

Please help me,
Why the collection print only one row in the template?

Thank you so much,
BienHV

Comment: remove `$collection->fetchItem();` and add after `  $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);` after `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);`

Comment: Hi Amit Bera, I changed it as your guide. public function But the result is not change. It still display only one result when sql query have 35 rows. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Try below code

```
 public function getProductCollection($cateId)
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $cateId]);
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Tirth Patel, When I get product info. The price default with $ currency value. How to update the price with other currency value when the user change currency on web? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fix my issue by add `$collection->getIterator();` after $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categoryIds]);

```
public function getProductCollection($categoryIds)
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categoryIds]);
        $collection->getIterator();

        return $collection;
    }
```